# OpenAPI type schemas are written to the Swagger type field

Tags: azure, go, terraform, azure-api-management

My question is in regard to API schemas in Azure API Management, resource type `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/schemas`.

A schema created through the Azure Portal is created with the content type `application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json` and written to `document/components/schemas`, which is the correct path for schema definitions in an OpenAPI definition.

Sample:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxx/apis/xxx/schemas/1629566051926",
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/schemas",
            "name": "1629566051926",
            "properties": {
                "contentType": "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json",
                "document": {
                    "components": {
                        "schemas": {
                            "patch-components-id-request-1": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "name": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "description": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "documentationURL": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "iacURL": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "duration": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "statusID": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "owner": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "count": 1
}
```

A schema created through the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2020-12-01/api-schema/create-or-update) or the [Go SDK](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go@v56.2.0+incompatible/services/apimanagement/mgmt/2020-12-01/apimanagement?utm_source=gopls#SchemaDocumentProperties) is set using `properties.document.definitions`, which leads to it being written to `document/definitions`, no matter the contentType.

Sample:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxx/apis/marble-dev-fctn/schemas/marbleschemas",
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/schemas",
            "name": "marbleschemas",
            "properties": {
                "contentType": "application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json",
                "document": {
                    "definitions": {
                        "patch-components-id-request-1": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "description": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "documentationURL": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "iacURL": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "duration": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "statusID": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "owner": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "count": 1
}
```

When setting the contentType to `application/vnd.ms-azure-apim.swagger.definitions+json` this is fine, but when setting the contentType to `application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json` two problems arise: The definition will not be included when exporting the OpenAPI Schema (at least when exporting from the Azure Portal, i have not tried any other way), since `definitions` is not a valid OpenAPI field, and it will not be shown in the Developer Portal.

As far as i understand it the definitons would need to be written to `document/components/schemas` for `application/vnd.oai.openapi.components+json` and `document/definitions` for `application/vnd.ms-azure-apim.swagger.definitions+json`.

I can import the definition to the correct path by setting it manually in an ARM Template or REST API call, but i am working on getting the terraform resource to work correctly, which is relying on the Go SDK. There might be a workaround for that as well but i would really like to find out if my understanding is wrong or if there might be a problem here.